# Inputs needed in completing the solution

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve a problem on multi dimensional array using Java. I need to print all the numbers appearing diagonally for a given two dimensional matrix. I have done for one scenario but not able to do for the rest of the elements

```
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    private static int[][] array = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12,}, {13,14,15,16}};

    public static void main(String args[]){

        for (int i=0;i<4; i++){
            for(int j=0;j < 4; j++){
                System.out.print(" "+ array[i][j] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
            int offset = 0;
            for(int j = offset;j <= i; j++){
                System.out.print("i >> "+i+" ");
                System.out.print("j >>  "+j);
                System.out.println(" == "+ array[i][i+offset] +" ");
            }
            offset++;
        }
    }
}
```

I started off writing the below code to get the first diagonal elements printed correctly.

```
    for (int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
        int offset = 0;
        System.out.print(array[i][i+offset] +" ");
        offset++;
    }
```

Output: `1 6 11 16`

But when I try to extend the same approach by adding inner for loop, I start iterating from `0` till `i` every time which results it printing the elements more than one time and not with correct output. Is my approach right or I am missing something when implementing the inner for loop.

The desired output should be like below:

```
1 6 11 16
2 7 12
3 8
4
5 10 15
6 11 16
7 12
8
9 14
10 15
11 16
12
```

This is not an assignment. I am just trying to improve my programming skills. Also please let me know the difficulty level of this problem on a scale of 1 to 5, 5 being hardest and 1 being simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for something like this:

```
private static int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12,}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

private static void f(int y, int x) {
    while ((y < 4) && (x < 4))
        System.out.print(array[y++][x++] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            f(i, j);
}
```